# How does Next.js - Vitest testing work with pages that have imported components? All my tests are failing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vitest

I have looked at the basic Next.js testing with Vitest documentation here:

```
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/testing/vitest
```

And have successfully tested different situations. However, my actual app has components that are confusing me on how to test them.

I have a Next.js application with this basic layout:

```
MyNextApp
|- __tests__/
|- ...
|- src
|  |- ...
|  |- components/
|  |  |- component01.tsx
|  |  |- component02.tsx
|  |  |- component03.tsx
|  |  |- ...
|  |  `- component-N.tsx
|  |- pages/
|  |  |- ...
|  |  |- index.js
|  |  `- ...
|  `- ...
`- ...
```

In `index.js`, I have something similar to this:

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import * as React from 'react';
import Component01 from '../components/component01';
import Component02 from '../components/component02';
import Component03 from '../components/component03';

export default function (){

    return(
        <>
            // ... JSX/HTML
            <Component01 />
            // ... JSX/HTML
            <Component02 />
            // ... JSX/HTML
            <Component03 />
            // ... JSX/HTML
        </>
    )
}
```

My components have the general form of:

```
export default function Component01() {
    return {
        <>
            // ...
        </>
    );
}
```

And this all works well and fine.

In `__tests__`, I have a test "ComponentTest.test.jsx" that looks like this:

```
import { expect, test } from 'vitest'
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import Component01 from '../src/components/Component01.tsx'
import Component02 from '../src/components/Component02.tsx'
import Component03 from '../src/components/Component03.tsx'

test('RenderComponent01', () => {
    render(<Component01 />)
    const theDialog = screen.getByRole('dialog');
    // -or-
    const theTestId = screen.getByTestId('myawesometest');
})
```

Now, when I run the tests

`> npm test`

They will all pass if I **JUST** use "render". However, if I try to target any specific section of the component (e.g., input, h1, img, dialog, etc.), the tests will fail.

`TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "input, h1, img, dialog, etc."`

`There are no accessible roles. But there might be some inaccessible roles. If you wish to access them, then set the 'hidden' option to 'true'. Learn more about this here: https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#byrole`

After that message, the console displays this:

```
Ignored nodes: comments, script, style
<body>
    <div>
        <div />
    </div>
</body>
```

It's like it is rendering the "index.js" without the imported components.

I have tried several variations of my "vitest.config.js" file:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
 
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  test: {
    environment: 'jsdom',
  },
})
    ↓    ↓    ↓    ↓    ↓

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  test: {
    include: ['**/*.test.*sx'],
    globals: true
  },
})
    ↓    ↓    ↓    ↓    ↓

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  test: {
    environment: 'happy-dom'
  },
});

    ↓    ↓    ↓    ↓    ↓

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(),vue()],
  test: {
    include: ['**/*.test.*sx'],
    globals: true,
    environment: 'happy-dom'
  },
})

    ↓    ↓    ↓    ↓    ↓

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  test: {
    include: ['**/*.test.*sx'],
    globals: true,
    environment: 'jsdom'
  },
})
```

But nothing seems to be working.

So how do I go about properly testing my app with these imported components?

---

**EDIT:** An actual example of one of my component files:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Dialog from '@mui/material/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@mui/material/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@mui/material/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@mui/material/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@mui/material/DialogTitle';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import Draggable from 'react-draggable';
import Table from '@mui/material/Table';
import TableBody from '@mui/material/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@mui/material/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@mui/material/TableContainer';
import TableRow from '@mui/material/TableRow';

function PaperComponent(props) {
  return (
    <Draggable handle="#draggable-dialog-title" cancel={'[class*="MuiDialogContent-root"]'}>
      <Paper {...props} />
    </Draggable>
  );
}

export default function AboutThis({ open, onClose }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Dialog open={open} onClose={onClose} PaperComponent={PaperComponent} aria-labelledby="draggable-dialog-title">
        <DialogTitle style={{ cursor: 'move' }} id="draggable-dialog-title">
          About This
        </DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText>
          <TableContainer component={Paper}>
            <Table>
              <TableBody>
                <TableRow>
                  <TableCell>stuff here ...</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow>
                  <TableCell>stuff here too ...</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              </TableBody>
            </Table>
          </TableContainer>
          </DialogContentText>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button disableRipple disableFocusRipple style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }} autoFocus onClick={onClose}> OK </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: (small note: that `index.js` doesn't contain html, it contains jsx even if the component names are the same as HTML tags, and is itself not js either, but jsx)

Comment: I just wanted to show that the included components were intermixed with other "code". I'll change it in my post to make things more clear.

Comment: Please include the code of your component 01. Also, not all the roles you listed are valid roles, eg. h1 doesn't have role `h1` but `heading` instead.

Comment: @DanMacak Component code added.

Comment: It seems that the component you are rendering is so conditioned that it just renders `<div>`. Take `AboutThis`, if the dialog is closed, it'd just render empty div. Start with this, render a simple component with a simple unconditioned markup and see if it is present in the DOM, and lemme know.

Comment: @DanMacak I will try this, thank you. As an aside, is there another testing framework for Next.js you would recommend out of the four listed on Next.js: Vitest, Jest, Playwright, or Cypress?

Comment: @DanMacak So, I used a very simple component, and it worked just like you said. Is there anything I can do to get my actual component to work? Thanks.

Comment: Playwright and Cypress are meant for different kind of tests - e2e. For unit/integration testing, I'd recommend Vitest over Jest since it's more modern.

Comment: Regarding your second question, you just have to make sure that when you are testing eg. `AboutThis`, that the `open` property on the Dialog is true. If you are not sure, you can debug it or `console.log` it.

Comment: @DanMacak Do I "make sure that when you are testing eg. AboutThis, that the open property on the Dialog is true" by passing a paremeter with the `render` function, or some other way?

Comment: In case of AboutThis by passing open prop, yes.